# What version of python is required to install electrum-ltc and electrum-dash in amazon linux instance?

Tags: electrum

I am trying to install different wallets on my amazon linux ec2 instance. I already have a working electrum-btc.

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx dash-electrum]$ python --version
Python 2.7.13
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx dash-electrum]$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.8
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx dash-electrum]$ uname -a
Linux ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx 4.9.85-38.58.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 14 01:17:26 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

But when Iam installing other clones for [litecoin](https://electrum-ltc.org/) and [dashcoin](http://electrum.dash.org/#features) pip install command fails.

> sudo `which pip3` install Electrum-DASH-2.9.4.tar.gz

```
  Running setup.py install for hidapi ... error
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-y3d9_mm3/hidapi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-ffxgn444/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_ext
cythoning hid.pyx to hid.c
building 'hid' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/hidapi
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/hidapi/libusb
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Ihidapi/hidapi -I/usr/include/libusb-1.0 -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c hid.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/hid.o
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Ihidapi/hidapi -I/usr/include/libusb-1.0 -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c hidapi/libusb/hid.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/hidapi/libusb/hid.o
hidapi/libusb/hid.c:26:0: warning: "_GNU_SOURCE" redefined
 #define _GNU_SOURCE /* needed for wcsdup() before glibc 2.10 */

<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
hidapi/libusb/hid.c:47:10: fatal error: libusb.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libusb.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-y3d9_mm3/hidapi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-ffxgn444/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-y3d9_mm3/hidapi/
```

What am I doing wrong? Can I install only one electrum wallet on one server?

Answer (score 1):

Your likely missing the `libusb` dependency.  Electrum doesn't spell it out in their repo, but I always build it with `trezorlib` and it explicitly requests it.  Here's what I got to work.

```
sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip cython3 libusb-1.0-0-dev libudev-dev python3-pyqt5
sudo -H python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
sudo -H python3 -m pip install https://some-path-to-tarball
```